# Fetching the data optimally in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

How can I write the resolvers such that I can generate database sub-query in each resolver and effectively combine all of them and fetch the data at once?

For the following schema :

```
type Node {
    index: Int!
    color: String!
    neighbors(first: Int = null): [Node!]!
}

type Query {
    nodes(color: String!): [Node!]!
}

schema {
    query: Query
}
```

To perform the following query :

```
{
    nodes(color: "red") {
        index
        neighbors(first: 5) {
            index
        }
    }
}
```

Data store:

In my data store, nodes and neighbors are stored in separate tables. I want to write a resolver so that we can fetch the required data optimally.

> If there are any similar examples, please share the details. (It would be helpful to get an answer in reference to graphql-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataFetchingEnvironment` provides access to sub-selections via `DataFetchingEnvironment#getSelectionSet`. This means, in your case, you'd be able to know from the `nodes` resolver that `neighbors` will also be required, so you could `JOIN` appropriately and prepare the result.

One **limitation** of the current implementation of `getSelectionSet` is that it doesn't provide info on **conditional selections**. So if you're dealing with interfaces and unions, you'll have to manually collect the sub-selection starting from `DataFetchingEnvironment#getField`. This will very likely be improved in the future releases of graphql-java.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended and most common way is to use a `data loader`.

A `data loader` collects the info about which `fields` to load from which `table` and which `where` filters to use.

I haven't worked with GraphQL in Java, so I can only give you directions how you could implement this yourself.

1. Create an instance of your data loader and pass it to your resolvers as the `context` argument.
2. Your resolvers should pass the `table name`, a list of `field names` and a list of `where conditions` to the data loader and return a promise.
3. Once all the resolvers have executed your data loader should combine those lists so you only end up with one query per table.
4. You should `remove duplicate field` names and `combine the where conditions` using the `or` keyword.
5. After the queries have executed you can return all of this data to your resolvers and let them filter the data (since we combined the conditions using the `or` keyword)
6. As an advanced feature your data loader could apply the where conditions before returning the data to the resolvers so that they don't have to filter them.